# Проблемы с BASS

Tags: c, bass.dll

Пытаюсь скомпилировать такой код:

```
/*
    BASS simple console player
    Copyright (c) 1999-2015 Un4seen Developments Ltd.
*/

#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#define BASSDEF(f) (WINAPI *f) // define the functions as pointers
#include "bass.h"

#ifdef _WIN32 // Windows
#include <conio.h>
#else // OSX/Linux
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <termios.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#define Sleep(x) usleep(x*1000)

int _kbhit()
{
    int r;
    fd_set rfds;
    struct timeval tv={0};
    struct termios term,oterm;
    tcgetattr(0,&oterm);
    memcpy(&term,&oterm,sizeof(term));
    cfmakeraw(&term);
    tcsetattr(0,TCSANOW,&term);
    FD_ZERO(&rfds);
    FD_SET(0,&rfds);
    r=select(1,&rfds,NULL,NULL,&tv);
    tcsetattr(0,TCSANOW,&oterm);
    return r;
}
#endif

// display error messages
void Error(const char *text) 
{
    printf("Error(%d): %s\n",BASS_ErrorGetCode(),text);
    BASS_Free();
    exit(0);
}

void ListDevices()
{
    BASS_DEVICEINFO di;
    int a;
    for (a=1;BASS_GetDeviceInfo(a,&di);a++) {
        if (di.flags&BASS_DEVICE_ENABLED) // enabled output device
            printf("dev %d: %s\n",a,di.name);
    }
}

void main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    DWORD chan,act,time,level;
    BOOL ismod;
    QWORD pos;
    int a,device=-1;

    printf("Simple console mode BASS example : MOD/MPx/OGG/WAV player\n"
            "---------------------------------------------------------\n");

    // check the correct BASS was loaded
    if (HIWORD(BASS_GetVersion())!=BASSVERSION) {
        printf("An incorrect version of BASS was loaded");
        return;
    }

    for (a=1;a<argc;a++) {
        if (!strcmp(argv[a],"-l")) {
            ListDevices();
            return;
        } else if (!strcmp(argv[a],"-d") && a+1<argc) device=atoi(argv[++a]);
        else break;
    }
    if (a!=argc-1) {
        printf("\tusage: contest [-l] [-d #] <file>\n"
            "\t-l = list devices\n"
            "\t-d = device number\n");
        return;
    }

    // initialize output device
    if (!BASS_Init(device,44100,0,0,NULL))
        Error("Can't initialize device");

    // try streaming the file/url
    if ((chan=BASS_StreamCreateFile(FALSE,argv[argc-1],0,0,BASS_SAMPLE_LOOP))
        || (chan=BASS_StreamCreateURL(argv[argc-1],0,BASS_SAMPLE_LOOP,0,0))) {
        pos=BASS_ChannelGetLength(chan,BASS_POS_BYTE);
        if (BASS_StreamGetFilePosition(chan,BASS_FILEPOS_DOWNLOAD)!=-1) {
            // streaming from the internet
            if (pos!=-1)
#ifdef _WIN32
                printf("streaming internet file [%I64d bytes]",pos);
#else
                printf("streaming internet file [%lld bytes]",pos);
#endif
            else
                printf("streaming internet file");
        } else
#ifdef _WIN32
            printf("streaming file [%I64d bytes]",pos);
#else
            printf("streaming file [%lld bytes]",pos);
#endif
        ismod=FALSE;
    } else {
        // try loading the MOD (with looping, sensitive ramping, and calculate the duration)
        if (!(chan=BASS_MusicLoad(FALSE,argv[argc-1],0,0,BASS_SAMPLE_LOOP|BASS_MUSIC_RAMPS|BASS_MUSIC_PRESCAN,1)))
            // not a MOD either
            Error("Can't play the file");
        { // count channels
            float dummy;
            for (a=0;BASS_ChannelGetAttribute(chan,BASS_ATTRIB_MUSIC_VOL_CHAN+a,&dummy);a++);
        }
        printf("playing MOD music \"%s\" [%u chans, %u orders]",
            BASS_ChannelGetTags(chan,BASS_TAG_MUSIC_NAME),a,(DWORD)BASS_ChannelGetLength(chan,BASS_POS_MUSIC_ORDER));
        pos=BASS_ChannelGetLength(chan,BASS_POS_BYTE);
        ismod=TRUE;
    }

    // display the time length
    if (pos!=-1) {
        time=(DWORD)BASS_ChannelBytes2Seconds(chan,pos);
        printf(" %u:%02u\n",time/60,time%60);
    } else // no time length available
        printf("\n");

    BASS_ChannelPlay(chan,FALSE);

    while (!_kbhit() && (act=BASS_ChannelIsActive(chan))) {
        // display some stuff and wait a bit
        level=BASS_ChannelGetLevel(chan);
        pos=BASS_ChannelGetPosition(chan,BASS_POS_BYTE);
        time=BASS_ChannelBytes2Seconds(chan,pos);
#ifdef _WIN32
        printf("pos %09I64u",pos);
#else
        printf("pos %09llu",pos);
#endif
        if (ismod) {
            pos=BASS_ChannelGetPosition(chan,BASS_POS_MUSIC_ORDER);
            printf(" (%03u:%03u)",LOWORD(pos),HIWORD(pos));
        }
        printf(" - %u:%02u - L ",time/60,time%60);
        if (act==BASS_ACTIVE_STALLED) { // playback has stalled
            printf("-- buffering : %05u --",(DWORD)BASS_StreamGetFilePosition(chan,BASS_FILEPOS_BUFFER));
        } else {
            for (a=27204;a>200;a=a*2/3) putchar(LOWORD(level)>=a?'*':'-');
            putchar(' ');
            for (a=210;a<32768;a=a*3/2) putchar(HIWORD(level)>=a?'*':'-');
        }
        printf(" R - cpu %.2f%%  \r",BASS_GetCPU());
        fflush(stdout);
        Sleep(50);
    }
    printf("                                                                             \r");

    // wind the frequency down...
    BASS_ChannelSlideAttribute(chan,BASS_ATTRIB_FREQ,1000,500);
    Sleep(300);
    // ...and fade-out to avoid a "click"
    BASS_ChannelSlideAttribute(chan,BASS_ATTRIB_VOL,-1,200);
    // wait for slide to finish
    while (BASS_ChannelIsSliding(chan,0)) Sleep(1);

    BASS_Free();
}
```

Этот пример доступен из коробки. От себя добавил только

```
#define BASSDEF(f) (WINAPI* f) // define the functions as pointers
```

иначе не собиралось. После запуска программа, не открывая окно, сразу падает. *gdb* пишет

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x00000000 in ?? ()

(gdb) bt
#0  0x00000000 in ?? ()
#1  0x004015c1 in main (argc=1, argv=0xdc15b0) at qks.c:68
```

Даже этот пример не работает:

```
#define BASSDEF(f) (WINAPI *f)
#include "bass.h"

int main() {
    BASS_Init(-1, 44100, 0, 0, NULL);
}
```

Компилирую так:

```
gcc.exe -m32 -Wall -Wextra -Wpedantic -lbass -mwindows qks.c -o qks.exe
```

*ОС* - Windows 10 x64; *GCC* - 4.9.2

**UPD**

Появился небольшой прогресс. Эта программа компилируется и успешно завершается:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <commctrl.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#define BASSDEF(f) (WINAPI *f)
#include "bass.h"

int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,LPSTR lpCmdLine, int nCmdShow) {
    (void) hPrevInstance, (void) lpCmdLine, (void) nCmdShow;

    HINSTANCE bass=LoadLibrary("bass.dll"); // load BASS
    BASS_Init=GetProcAddress(bass,"BASS_Init"); // get BASS_Init
    BASS_Init(-1,44100,0,NULL,NULL) // call BASS_Init
}
```

Вот что написано в документации:

> The downside is that you have to manually import each function that
>   you use, with the `GetProcAddress` function. But it has been made a lot
>   simpler to import BASS this way by the use of the `BASSDEF #define`.
>   Here's a small example:
>
> ```
> #define BASSDEF(f) (WINAPI *f) // define the functions as pointers
> #include "bass.h" ... HINSTANCE bass=LoadLibrary("BASS.DLL"); // load BASS
> BASS_Init=GetProcAddress(bass,"BASS_Init"); // get BASS_Init
> BASS_Init(-1,44100,0,hWnd,NULL); // call BASS_Init
> ```

Однако при попытке получить адрес других функций ловлю предупреждение:

```
warning: assignment from incompatible pointer type
  BASS_GetVersion=GetProcAddress(bass,"BASS_GetVersion");
```

И если вызвать эту функцию (или какие-нибудь другие), то снова происходит `SIGSEGV`.

**UPD 2**

Приведенный выше пример работает, если добавит в начало тела `main` эти строки:

```
HINSTANCE bass=LoadLibrary("bass.dll"); // load BASS
BASS_Init=GetProcAddress(bass,"BASS_Init"); // get BASS_Init
BASS_GetVersion=GetProcAddress(bass,"BASS_GetVersion");
BASS_Free=GetProcAddress(bass,"BASS_Free");
BASS_SetVolume=GetProcAddress(bass,"BASS_SetVolume");
BASS_SetConfig=GetProcAddress(bass,"BASS_SetConfig");
BASS_SampleFree=GetProcAddress(bass,"BASS_SampleFree");
BASS_SampleLoad=GetProcAddress(bass,"BASS_SampleLoad");
BASS_SampleGetChannel=GetProcAddress(bass,"BASS_SampleGetChannel");
BASS_ChannelPlay=GetProcAddress(bass,"BASS_ChannelPlay");
BASS_ChannelStop=GetProcAddress(bass,"BASS_ChannelStop");
BASS_GetVolume=GetProcAddress(bass,"BASS_GetVolume");
BASS_GetVersion=GetProcAddress(bass,"BASS_GetVersion");
BASS_GetCPU=GetProcAddress(bass,"BASS_GetCPU");
BASS_Pause=GetProcAddress(bass,"BASS_Pause");
BASS_Start=GetProcAddress(bass,"BASS_Start");
BASS_MusicFree=GetProcAddress(bass,"BASS_MusicFree");
BASS_MusicLoad=GetProcAddress(bass,"BASS_MusicLoad");
BASS_ChannelSetAttribute=GetProcAddress(bass,"BASS_ChannelSetAttribute");
BASS_StreamCreateFile=GetProcAddress(bass,"BASS_StreamCreateFile");
BASS_ErrorGetCode=GetProcAddress(bass,"BASS_ErrorGetCode");
BASS_StreamCreateURL=GetProcAddress(bass, "BASS_StreamCreateURL");
BASS_ChannelGetLength=GetProcAddress(bass, "BASS_ChannelGetLength");
BASS_StreamGetFilePosition=GetProcAddress(bass, "BASS_StreamGetFilePosition");
BASS_ChannelGetAttribute=GetProcAddress(bass, "BASS_ChannelGetAttribute");
BASS_ChannelGetTags=GetProcAddress(bass, "BASS_ChannelGetTags");
BASS_ChannelGetLength=GetProcAddress(bass, "BASS_ChannelGetLength");
BASS_ChannelBytes2Seconds=GetProcAddress(bass, "BASS_ChannelBytes2Seconds");
BASS_ChannelIsActive=GetProcAddress(bass, "BASS_ChannelIsActive");
BASS_ChannelGetLevel=GetProcAddress(bass, "BASS_ChannelGetLevel");
BASS_ChannelGetPosition=GetProcAddress(bass, "BASS_ChannelGetPosition");
BASS_ChannelSlideAttribute=GetProcAddress(bass, "BASS_ChannelSlideAttribute");
```

Одно большое "**НО**":
Звук воспроизводиться при запуске из командной строки (cmd.exe, ConEmu), но нет текстовой информации. Т.е. я запускаю программу и она работает в фоне, в терминале сразу появляется приглашение ввода:

```
user@LAPTOP-OIQUIP0K C:\Users\user\Documents\Projects\sound 
> qks.exe -d -1 "C:\Users\user\Music\Radiohead\Creep.mp3"   

user@LAPTOP-OIQUIP0K C:\Users\user\Documents\Projects\sound 
>
```

Однако вся текстовая информация (звук тоже работает) появляется во встроенной консоли `SublimeText 3`:

```
C:\Users\user\Documents\Projects\sound>qks.exe -d -1 "C:\Users\user\Music\Radiohead\Creep.mp3" 
Simple console mode BASS example : MOD/MPx/OGG/WAV player
---------------------------------------------------------
streaming file [41587200 bytes] 3:55
pos 000000136 - 0:00 - L ------------- ------------- R - cpu 0.00%  
pos 000005944 - 0:00 - L ------------- ------------- R - cpu 0.00%  
pos 000014808 - 0:00 - L ------------- ------------- R - cpu 0.00%  
pos 000023728 - 0:00 - L ------------- ------------- R - cpu 0.00%  
pos 000032628 - 0:00 - L ------------- ------------- R - cpu 0.07%  
pos 000041584 - 0:00 - L ---********** **********--- R - cpu 0.07%  
pos 000050496 - 0:00 - L -----******** ********----- R - cpu 0.14%  
pos 000059536 - 0:00 - L -----******** *********---- R - cpu 0.14%  
pos 000068572 - 0:00 - L -----******** *********---- R - cpu 0.19%  
pos 000077544 - 0:00 - L -----******** ********----- R - cpu 0.19%  
pos 000086464 - 0:00 - L -----******** *********---- R - cpu 0.25%  
pos 000095364 - 0:00 - L -----******** ********----- R - cpu 0.25%
...
```

Информация о компиляторе (gcc -v):

```
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=gcc.exe
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=c:/mingw64/bin/../libexec/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.8.1/lto-wrapper.exe
Target: x86_64-w64-mingw32
Configured with: ../../../src/gcc-4.8.1/configure --build=x86_64-w64-mingw32 --enable-targets=all --enable-languages=ada,c,c++,fortran,lto,objc,obj-c++ --enable-libgomp --enable-lto --enable-graphite --enable-cxx-flags=-DWINPTHREAD_STATIC --enable-libstdcxx-debug --enable-threads=posix --enable-version-specific-runtime-libs --enable-fully-dynamic-string --enable-libstdcxx-threads --enable-libstdcxx-time --with-gnu-ld --disable-werror --disable-nls --disable-win32-registry --prefix=/mingw64tdm --with-local-prefix=/mingw64tdm --with-pkgversion=tdm64-2 --with-bugurl=http://tdm-gcc.tdragon.net/bugs
Thread model: posix
gcc version 4.8.1 (tdm64-2)
```

Отладка:

```
user@LAPTOP-OIQUIP0K C:\Users\user\Documents\Projects\sound
> gdb.exe qks.exe
GNU gdb (GDB) 7.7.50.20140303-cvs
Copyright (C) 2014 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.  Type "show copying"
and "show warranty" for details.
This GDB was configured as "i686-pc-mingw32".
Type "show configuration" for configuration details.
For bug reporting instructions, please see:
<http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/bugs/>.
Find the GDB manual and other documentation resources online at:
<http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/documentation/>.
For help, type "help".
Type "apropos word" to search for commands related to "word".

This binary was built by Equation Solution <http://www.Equation.com>...
Reading symbols from qks.exe...done.
(gdb) b main
Breakpoint 1 at 0x4015c5: file qks.c, line 59.
(gdb) r -d -1 "C:\Users\user\Music\Radiohead\Creep.mp3"
Starting program: C:\Users\user\Documents\Projects\sound\qks.exe -d -1 "C:\Users\user\Music\Radiohead\Creep.mp3"
[New Thread 2708.0x16f4]
[New Thread 2708.0x4c0]

Breakpoint 1, main (argc=4, argv=0xab2390) at qks.c:59
59              HINSTANCE bass=LoadLibrary("bass.dll"); // load BASS
(gdb) n
[New Thread 2708.0xd28]
60              BASS_Init=GetProcAddress(bass,"BASS_Init"); // get BASS_Init
(gdb)
61              BASS_GetVersion=GetProcAddress(bass,"BASS_GetVersion");
(gdb)
62              BASS_Free=GetProcAddress(bass,"BASS_Free");
(gdb)
63              BASS_SetVolume=GetProcAddress(bass,"BASS_SetVolume");
(gdb)
64              BASS_SetConfig=GetProcAddress(bass,"BASS_SetConfig");
(gdb)
65              BASS_SampleFree=GetProcAddress(bass,"BASS_SampleFree");
(gdb)
66              BASS_SampleLoad=GetProcAddress(bass,"BASS_SampleLoad");
(gdb)
67              BASS_SampleGetChannel=GetProcAddress(bass,"BASS_SampleGetChannel");
(gdb)
68              BASS_ChannelPlay=GetProcAddress(bass,"BASS_ChannelPlay");
(gdb)
69              BASS_ChannelStop=GetProcAddress(bass,"BASS_ChannelStop");
(gdb)
70              BASS_GetVolume=GetProcAddress(bass,"BASS_GetVolume");
(gdb)
71              BASS_GetVersion=GetProcAddress(bass,"BASS_GetVersion");
(gdb)
72              BASS_GetCPU=GetProcAddress(bass,"BASS_GetCPU");
(gdb)
73              BASS_Pause=GetProcAddress(bass,"BASS_Pause");
(gdb)
74              BASS_Start=GetProcAddress(bass,"BASS_Start");
(gdb)
75              BASS_MusicFree=GetProcAddress(bass,"BASS_MusicFree");
(gdb)
76              BASS_MusicLoad=GetProcAddress(bass,"BASS_MusicLoad");
(gdb)
77              BASS_ChannelSetAttribute=GetProcAddress(bass,"BASS_ChannelSetAttribute");
(gdb)
78              BASS_StreamCreateFile=GetProcAddress(bass,"BASS_StreamCreateFile");
(gdb)
79              BASS_ErrorGetCode=GetProcAddress(bass,"BASS_ErrorGetCode");
(gdb)
80              BASS_StreamCreateURL=GetProcAddress(bass, "BASS_StreamCreateURL");
(gdb)
81              BASS_ChannelGetLength=GetProcAddress(bass, "BASS_ChannelGetLength");
(gdb)
82              BASS_StreamGetFilePosition=GetProcAddress(bass, "BASS_StreamGetFilePosition");
(gdb)
83              BASS_ChannelGetAttribute=GetProcAddress(bass, "BASS_ChannelGetAttribute");
(gdb)
84              BASS_ChannelGetTags=GetProcAddress(bass, "BASS_ChannelGetTags");
(gdb)
85              BASS_ChannelGetLength=GetProcAddress(bass, "BASS_ChannelGetLength");
(gdb)
86              BASS_ChannelBytes2Seconds=GetProcAddress(bass, "BASS_ChannelBytes2Seconds");
(gdb)
87              BASS_ChannelIsActive=GetProcAddress(bass, "BASS_ChannelIsActive");
(gdb)
88              BASS_ChannelGetLevel=GetProcAddress(bass, "BASS_ChannelGetLevel");
(gdb)
89              BASS_ChannelGetPosition=GetProcAddress(bass, "BASS_ChannelGetPosition");
(gdb)
90              BASS_ChannelSlideAttribute=GetProcAddress(bass, "BASS_ChannelSlideAttribute");
(gdb)
95          int a,device=-1;
(gdb)
97          printf("Simple console mode BASS example : MOD/MPx/OGG/WAV player\n"
(gdb)
101         if (HIWORD(BASS_GetVersion())!=BASSVERSION) {
(gdb)
0x744d59c6 in ?? ()
(gdb) ni
0x744b10f9 in ?? () from C:\Users\user\Documents\Projects\sound\bass.dll
(gdb)
0x744b45c5 in ?? () from C:\Users\user\Documents\Projects\sound\bass.dll
(gdb)
0x744b45c6 in ?? () from C:\Users\user\Documents\Projects\sound\bass.dll
(gdb)
0x744b45cc in ?? () from C:\Users\user\Documents\Projects\sound\bass.dll
(gdb)
0x744b45d2 in ?? () from C:\Users\user\Documents\Projects\sound\bass.dll
(gdb)
0x744b45d4 in ?? () from C:\Users\user\Documents\Projects\sound\bass.dll
(gdb)
0x744b45d6 in ?? () from C:\Users\user\Documents\Projects\sound\bass.dll
(gdb)
0x744b45ee in ?? () from C:\Users\user\Documents\Projects\sound\bass.dll
(gdb)
0x744b45f0 in ?? () from C:\Users\user\Documents\Projects\sound\bass.dll
(gdb)
0x744b45f1 in ?? () from C:\Users\user\Documents\Projects\sound\bass.dll
(gdb)
0x744b10fe in ?? () from C:\Users\user\Documents\Projects\sound\bass.dll
(gdb)
0x744b1101 in ?? () from C:\Users\user\Documents\Projects\sound\bass.dll
(gdb)
0x744b1103 in ?? () from C:\Users\user\Documents\Projects\sound\bass.dll
(gdb)
0x744b1104 in ?? () from C:\Users\user\Documents\Projects\sound\bass.dll
(gdb)
0x744d59cb in ?? ()
(gdb)
0x744d59d0 in ?? ()
(gdb)
0x00401976 in main (argc=4, argv=0xab2390) at qks.c:101
101         if (HIWORD(BASS_GetVersion())!=BASSVERSION) {
(gdb) n
106         for (a=1;a<argc;a++) {
(gdb)
107             if (!strcmp(argv[a],"-l")) {
(gdb)
110             } else if (!strcmp(argv[a],"-d") && a+1<argc) device=atoi(argv[++a]);
(gdb)
106         for (a=1;a<argc;a++) {
(gdb)
107             if (!strcmp(argv[a],"-l")) {
(gdb)
110             } else if (!strcmp(argv[a],"-d") && a+1<argc) device=atoi(argv[++a]);
(gdb)
113         if (a!=argc-1) {
(gdb)
121         if (!BASS_Init(device,44100,0,0,NULL))
(gdb)
0x744d3dc5 in ?? ()
(gdb) ni
0x744d3dc6 in ?? ()
(gdb)
0x744d3dca in ?? ()
(gdb)
0x744d3dcd in ?? ()
(gdb)
0x744d3dd3 in ?? ()
(gdb)
0x744d3dd4 in ?? ()
(gdb)
0x744d3dd5 in ?? ()
(gdb)
0x744b462e in ?? () from C:\Users\user\Documents\Projects\sound\bass.dll
(gdb)
0x744b4630 in ?? () from C:\Users\user\Documents\Projects\sound\bass.dll
(gdb)
0x744b4644 in ?? () from C:\Users\user\Documents\Projects\sound\bass.dll
(gdb)
0x744b4646 in ?? () from C:\Users\user\Documents\Projects\sound\bass.dll
(gdb)
0x744d3dda in ?? ()
(gdb)
0x744d3ddc in ?? ()
(gdb)
0x744d3dde in ?? ()
(gdb)
0x744d3de0 in ?? ()
(gdb)
0x744d3de2 in ?? ()
(gdb)
0x744d3de3 in ?? ()
(gdb)
0x744d3da9 in ?? ()
(gdb)
0x744d3daa in ?? ()
(gdb)
0x744b470b in ?? () from C:\Users\user\Documents\Projects\sound\bass.dll
(gdb)
0x744b4710 in ?? () from C:\Users\user\Documents\Projects\sound\bass.dll
(gdb)
[New Thread 2708.0x109c]
[New Thread 2708.0x1098]
[New Thread 2708.0xcdc]
[New Thread 2708.0x760]
[New Thread 2708.0x1674]
[New Thread 2708.0x1834]
[New Thread 2708.0x390]
[New Thread 2708.0x1314] <-- здесь начинает играть музыка
                             программу пришлось "убивать" через диспетчер
                             задач, т.к. музыка играет заново снова и снова.   
[Thread 2708.0xd28 exited with code 1]
[Thread 2708.0x4c0 exited with code 1]
[Thread 2708.0x109c exited with code 1]
[Thread 2708.0xcdc exited with code 1]
[Thread 2708.0x1098 exited with code 1]
[Thread 2708.0x1674 exited with code 1]
[Thread 2708.0x760 exited with code 1]
[Thread 2708.0x1834 exited with code 1]
[Thread 2708.0x390 exited with code 1]
[Thread 2708.0x1314 exited with code 1]
[Inferior 1 (process 2708) exited with code 01]
```

Система:

```
OS: Windows 10 x64
CPU: AMD A9-9410 RADEON R5, COMPUTE CORES 2C+3G  2.90 GHz
```

Команды компиляции и запуска:

```
gcc.exe -g -std=c11 -m32 -Wall -Wextra -Wpedantic -lbass -mwindows qks.c -o qks.exe
qks.exe -d -1 "C:\Users\user\Music\Eminem\Rap God.mp3"
```

Comment: запускайте свое приложение с под gdb. То есть, откройте терминал в той папке, где приложение, пишите `gdb имяприложения.exe`, потом `run`, что бы запустить и когда упадет -  `bt` - посмотреть стек. Вот его и показывайте. Возможно, если стек будет нечитаемый, пересоберите бинарь с параметром `-g`.

Comment: @KoVadim, `(gdb) bt
#0  0x00000000 in ?? ()
#1  0x004015c1 in main (argc=1, argv=0xdc15b0) at qks.c:68`

Comment: если я все правильно посчитал, то падает прямо на самом первом вызове - BASS_GetVersion()  Похоже, что библиотека подключилась как то плохо. Или неправильно инициализировалась.

Comment: Ничего не выводит в консоль из-за опции -mwindows. Вам нужно -mconsole.

Comment: Кстати, вам принципиально использовать gcc? Для студии у BASS есть LIB-файл, так что можно обойтись без GetProcAddress.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Есть такая штука - [ABI](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%94%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%84%D0%B5%D0%B9%D1%81_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9) - то есть описание того, как функция/класс будет представлена в бинарном виде. Это очень важно, когда линкуются два разных куска кода (например, exe и статическая библиотка) или просто вызываются (например, обращение к dll). В некоторых случаях линковщик (а это его работа) может проверить, что интерфейс не совпадает и поднять панику. А может и не знать или проигнорировать.

Если два куска кода не совместимы на уровне ABI, то может произойти все что угодно. Самый простой пример - вызывающая сторона ожидает параметры в регистрах, а вызываемая - в стеке. Что именно прочитается со стека - никто не знает. В лучшем случае упадет с Access violation.

В случае чистого Си эту проблему достаточно хорошо решили (всякие stdcall, cdecl и подобное). А вот в случае с++ все сильно сложнее - есть классы, а им нужно хранить данные, которые никак не стандартизированы. Даже если использовать только gcc, он может использовать различное ABI. Из последнего, на что я лично натолкнулся, это сильно измененный ABI при переходе от 4.9.х на 5.4.х (он вроде после 5.2 поменялся). [Здесь](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/abi.html) есть много деталей.

**Теперь ближе к проблеме.** По внешнему виду файла обычно сложно догадаться, какой версией компилятора он собран. Но её можно попробовать угадать. Судя по всему, там внутри все собрано с помощью vc6 (это очень древнее существо) и более-менее свежие gcc с ним поэтому и не совместимы. А старые - да. @VadimTagil просто повезло, что он угадал правильную версию.

**Что делать?** использовать gcc 3.4 как не очень, как по мне, поэтому, лучше взять сорцы и пересобрать их именно тем gcc, которым будет собираться все остальное. Благое дело, там есть makefile и студийный проект.

Comment: Не согласен. Во первых, мне не "повезло", я просто использовал версию GCC, которая осталась на компьютере вместе с установленной пару лет назад CodeBlocks. Только что обновился до последней версии с GCC 4.9.2 и все также отлично работает. Во-вторых, функции Bass.dll используют соглашение о вызове WINAPI (a.k.a stdcall). Оно вполне четко определяет, что параметры передаются через стек, а возвращаемое значение - через регистр. Такие вещи от версии к версии компилятора не меняются, иначе был бы полный хаос.

Comment: Единственный случай - переход от x86 к x64, там соглашение меняется, поэтому я предположил об этом в первую очередь.  Но раз это не так, значит у автора локальная проблема с конфигурацией IDE, которая случайно исчезла при смене версии GCC.

Comment: Вся проблема в том, что для многих людей препроцессинг, компиляция и линковка называются одним словом - компиляция. Да, обычно в случае gcc их делает одна и та же программа. Но может быть и по другому. И линковку может делать совсем другой линковщик. А тут простор для багов широкий.

Answer (score 3):

Ну, предупреждение "assignment from incompatible pointer type" вполне логично. GetProcAddress возвращает указатель на функцию с неопределенным списком параметров, возвращающую int. Приведение к любым другим указателям выведет это предупреждение. Его можно игнорировать.

Что касается Segmentation Fault, у меня ничего такого не наблюдается. BASS_GetVersion, BASS_GetDeviceInfo нормально работают. Либо вы не ту версию DLL-ки подкладываете (32-битную вместо 64-битной или наоборот), либо какая-то локальная проблема с вашей системой.

UPD: На всякий случай, мой рабочий пример:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#define BASSDEF(f) (WINAPI *f) // define the functions as pointers
#include "bass.h"
#include <conio.h>

void ListDevices()
{
    BASS_DEVICEINFO di;
    int a;
    for (a=1;BASS_GetDeviceInfo(a,&di);a++) {
        if (di.flags&BASS_DEVICE_ENABLED) // enabled output device
            printf("dev %d: %s\n",a,di.name);
    }
}

void main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    HINSTANCE bass=LoadLibrary("BASS.DLL"); // load BASS
    BASS_Init=GetProcAddress(bass,"BASS_Init");
    BASS_GetVersion=GetProcAddress(bass,"BASS_GetVersion");
    BASS_GetDeviceInfo=GetProcAddress(bass,"BASS_GetDeviceInfo");

    // check the correct BASS was loaded
    DWORD ver;
    ver=BASS_GetVersion();
    if (HIWORD(ver)!=BASSVERSION) {
        printf("An incorrect version of BASS was loaded");
        return;
    }
    else
    {
        printf("BASS version is %d\n\n",ver);
    }

    ListDevices();
    system("pause");
}
```

Компилируется и успешно работает (выводит список устройств), тестировалось на:

- Windows 7 x64
- GCC 3.4.2, 4.9.2 (32-битный режим)
- BASS 2.4

Comment: А чем компилируете, студией или gcc?

Comment: @KoVadim gcc 3.4.2

Comment: у gcc время от времени меняется ABI, Иногда линковщик об этом предупреждает, а иногда - нет и приложения падают. Думаю, тут как раз эта ситуация.

Comment: DLL-ка правильная. Попробую поставить другую версию gcc.

Comment: @KoVadim, вы были правы. После даунгрейда gcc все заработало) Думаю, будет лучше, если вы оформите комментарий как ответ, а я его приму)

Comment: @Eanmos Я бы не спешил с выводами. У меня с версией 4.9.2 все также отлично работает.

Comment: @VadimTagil, да, ничего не понимаю. У меня ваш пример не работает gcc 4.8.1 (tdm64-2)

Comment: @Eanmos не работает - это падает, или просто текст не выводит? Вы какой-то IDE пользуетесь, или сами в консоли компилируете? А то у вас параметры компилятора сомнительные. Я компилирую в CodeBlocks с параметрами по умолчанию для проекта "Консольное приложение"

Comment: @VadimTagil, сам компилирую в консоли. Текст теперь выводит, после того, как заменил `-mwindow` на `-mconsole`. Спасибо за помощь!

Answer (score 0):

Может то, что от себя добавлено, должно так выглядеть:

```
#ifndef BASSDEF
#ifdef WIN32
#define BASSDEF(f) WINAPI f
#else
#define BASSDEF(f) f
#endif
#endif
```

Взято отсюда
https://github.com/kusma/spaceflowers/blob/master/bassmod/bassmod.h

Или просто вот так:

```
#define BASSDEF(f) WINAPI f
```

https://github.com/sonicretro/sadx-mod-loader/blob/master/extlib/bass/bass.h

Comment: Так не собирается. Свой вариант я в офф. справке нашел.